# @Autowired in bean not in spring context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to springs. Is there an alternative for autowired to be used in a ordinary java bean which is not present in spring context.

Comment: so you want to inject a spring managed bean into non-managed POJO?

Comment: Do you want autowiring to work for the beans that you instantiate, rather than the spring-container, is that what you want?

Comment: @Funtik, yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using Spring [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) with some `AspectJ` magic.

If you need a detailed explanation, here is the [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html).

And here is a brief overview of how it can be achieved.

First you have some bean that you want injected somewhere:

```
@Component
public class InjectedClass {
    // ...
}
```

Then, you have a class that is not spring-container managed, that you want to instantiate. You want autowiring to work with this class. You mark it as a [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html).

```
@Configurable
public class NonContainerManagedClass  {

    @Autowired
    private InjectedClass injected;

    // ...
}
```

Now you need to tell spring that you want this non-container managed autowiring to work. So you put the following in your spring configuration.

```
<context:load-time-weaver />
<context:spring-configured />
```

Now, since this kind of thing requires modification of the bytecodes of your [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) class. So you tell Tomcat to use a different `classloader`. You can do so by creating a `context.xml` in your application's `META-INF` diretory and putting the following in there.

```
<Context path="/youWebAppName">
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"
        useSystemClassLoaderAsParent="false"/>
</Context>
```

Now, Tomcat needs to find that `classloader`. You can ensure that by putting Spring's `spring-tomcat-weaver.jar` (probably named `org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-<version>.jar`) in your tomcat installation's `lib` directory, and voila, the aspectj magic starts working. For classes that are annotated with [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) annotation, the `@Autowired` dependencies are resolved automatically; even if the instances are created outside of the spring-container.

This is probably the only way to make that work with Spring, in a clean manner. Make sure that you have appropriate dependencies in your `classpath`.

Another way would be to use the full [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/index.html) functionality and providing custom aspects around all your constructors and handling the dependency-injection yourself.